# How can I get values from mysql db, replace some text from the values, and then get the averate of the numeric values?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a column in mysql db that has values such as '34343|dollar' and '2343|dollar'. I wish to get all the column values, then remove the '|dollar' string and get the average of the numbers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: And this, boys and girls, is why we don't violate first normal form of relational databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql, storing multiple value in single column from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804841/mysql-storing-multiple-value-in-single-column-from-another-table)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select AVG(CONVERT(REPLACE(col,'|dollar',''), SIGNED INTEGER)) from my_table;
```

'col' is your column that has the values as you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, after that how do I get the result to echo it? seems that it is an object and not a string. thanks.